# What are the files in my go-ethereum configuration directory?

Tags: go-ethereum, configuration

When I look into my go-ethereum (geth) configuration directory, I see the following files and directories:

```
 $ ls -alF ~/.ethereum/
total 176
drwxr-xr-x  8 pi pi   4096 Jan 20 07:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 pi pi   4096 Jan 20 07:10 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   4096 Aug 31 06:16 blockchain/
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi 131072 Jan 22 07:40 chaindata/
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   4096 Jan 20 07:19 dapp/
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   4096 Aug 31 06:20 extra/
srw-------  1 pi pi      0 Jan 20 07:19 geth.ipc=
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi     53 Oct 10 10:17 history*
-rw-------  1 pi pi     64 Aug 21 12:19 nodekey
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   4096 Jan 22 04:18 nodes/
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi  12288 Aug 31 06:20 state/
```

Can you explain the purpose of each of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the files in your directory listing are old and the result of maintaining the files after upgrades no longer using them. Necessary files can be summarized like so:

- `chaindata/` (directory of chain and state data)
- `dapp/` (directory for placeholder of dapp data)
- `geth.ipc` (file for inter-process-communication as used by Mist)
- `history` (file for console command history from `geth attach` or `geth console`)
- `keystore/` (directory for encrypted private keys)
- `nodekey` (file of public key used by peers to connect with)
- `nodes/` (directory peer connection data, used to establish network on start)

The following directories are from an old version and can be safely discarded:

- `blockchain/` (old, can be discarded)
- `state` (old, can be discarded)
- `extra/` (old, can be discarded)

In general , the most important item to back up is the `keystore/` directory, since it contains the encrypted private keys used to control Ethereum accounts. **These keys cannot be recovered if lost.** Additionally, if you are running the node as a public peer or bootnode, backing up the `nodekey` file is important to maintain the same peer key when changing devices. Most other files can be reproduced by synchronizing with the network again.